# "Cannot find symbol error ", even after using import statement

Tags: java, swing, jgrasp

Following an online tutorial I am trying to create a GUI in java using swing.
I have tried searching for an ansewer online but i couldn.t find any.
Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Container;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing;

//Create JFrame Container
public class River
{
public River()
{
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contentPanel = jframe.getContentPane();
    GroupLayout grouplayout = new GroupLayout(contentPanel);
    contentPanel.setLayout(grouplayout);

    JLabel clickMe = new JLabel("Click Here");
    JButton button = new JButton("This Button");

    grouplayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        grouplayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(clickMe)
            .addGap(10,20,100)
            .addComponent(button));

    grouplayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(clickMe)
            .addComponent(button));

    jframe.setTitle("Our GUI");
    jframe.pack();
    jframe.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) //main method
{
    new River();
} // end of main
}//end River class
```

However when i try run the code using JGRASP i get the follow errors:

River.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import javax.swing.Container;
                  ^
    symbol:   class Container
    location: package javax.swing
    River.java:8: error: package javax does not exist
    import javax.swing;
            ^
    River.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        Container contentPanel = jframe.getContentPane();
        ^
    symbol:   class Container
    location: class River
    River.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        JButton button = new JButton("This Button");
        ^
    symbol:   class JButton
    location: class River
    River.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        JButton button = new JButton("This Button");
                             ^
    symbol:   class JButton
    location: class River
    River.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            ^
    symbol:   variable groupLayout
    location: class River
    6 errors

```
----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: *even after using import statement* - so the trick is to read the API for the class in question to make sure you are using the proper import statement.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
import javax.swing.Container;
```

with

```
import java.awt.Container;
```

Comment: actual just using import javax.swing.* and javax.awt.* worked

Comment: Just keep in mind that `javax.awt.*` will import all classes of the package, `javax.awt` and therefore, it is not a recommended way of importing the classes. We should import only those types which are required by our program.